# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the xService

Tags: nestjs

error (cont): Please make sure that the argument PrismaService at index [0] is available in the Assoc_Page_TagModule context.

There are no errors in the code.

When I attempt > npm run start:dev

I initially get:  Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
Then an error:

[ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the Assoc_Page_TagService (?). Please make sure that the argument PrismaService at index [0] is available in the Assoc_Page_TagModule context.

What is the argument at index [0]?   Why is it expecting an argument?

Assoc_Page_Tag.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from '../database';
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class Assoc_Page_TagService {
  constructor(private readonly prisma: PrismaService) {}

  Assoc_Page_TagsAll() {
    return Promise.all([
      this.prisma.assoc_Page_Tag.findMany()]).then(([records, total]) => {
        return {
          records,
           metadata: { total },
        };
      });
  }
```

Assoc_Page_Tag.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { Assoc_Page_TagController } from './Assoc_Page_Tag.controller';
import { Assoc_Page_TagService } from './Assoc_Page_Tag.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [Assoc_Page_TagController],
  providers: [Assoc_Page_TagService],
  exports: [Assoc_Page_TagService],
})

export class Assoc_Page_TagModule {}
```

Assoc_Page_Tag.controller.ts

```
import {
  Body,Controller,Get,Param,ParseIntPipe,Put,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Assoc_Page_TagService } from './Assoc_Page_Tag.service';
import { RESOURCE_BASE_ROUTE } from '../constant';
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

const Route = RESOURCE_BASE_ROUTE.assoc_Page_Tag

@Controller()
export class Assoc_Page_TagController {
  constructor(private readonly assoc_page_tagService: Assoc_Page_TagService) {}

  @Get(`${Route}`)
  all() {
    return this.assoc_page_tagService.Assoc_Page_TagsAll();
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Assoc_Page_TagModule } from './Assoc_Page_Tag';

@Module({
  imports: [
    Assoc_Page_TagModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: "the argument at index [0]" is `prisma` (of type `PrismaService`)

Comment: That's what I needed!  Thanks Micael

Answer (score 0):

Missing reference to PrismaModule - which exports PrismaService

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { PrismaModule } from './database';

import { Assoc_Page_TagModule } from './Assoc_Page_Tag';

@Module({
  imports: [
    PrismaModule,
    Assoc_Page_TagModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```